# selling job on the patriarch

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anyone help me about exact meaning of the following sentence?

> The group also recognized that their proposal required a more difficult selling job on the patriarch.

Of course. I should add the patriarch was opposed to the proposal. I could not find any meaning for "selling job" suitable for the context, but, I think it means "satisfying the patriarch by offering a good post to him" albeit, I am not sure.

Comment: Could you add the source?

Comment: @marcellothearcane another of Arya's 10+ questions so far on *The Shah, the Islamic Revolution and the United States* by Darioush Bayandor - this one from page 273.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very slangy usage, imho merging two somewhat *different* usages.

***To do a job on someone / something*** usually means to deliberately do something that has a harmful impact on them.

But ***to do a selling job*** [**to, with,** or **on** someone] means to persuade someone to accept some proposition (often using unconventional or extreme methods) that they would normally resist.

In the cited context, the group knew that the patriarch wouldn't be naturally inclined to accept their proposal (perhaps he was initially even *hostile* to it). Hence it would be difficult to "sell" their ideas to him (where ***to sell*** means ***to convince others of the truth or value*** of something - compare *I don't **buy** that! = I don't **believe** that!*).

Note that it's not *necessarily* implied that the group should offer *inducements* (a good post, a bribe, or whatever) to the patriarch in order to persuade him to support their proposal. They might achieve their aim by convincing him this would be the *morally correct* thing to do, for example. Or by *threatening dire consequences* (rebellion?) if he refused to support them